# recursive code for finding the height of a binary tree

Tags: c++, recursion, data-structures, scope, binary-tree

I am trying to find the height of a binary tree and here is my attempt at the same

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stack>
using namespace std;
int total = 0;
int length = -1;
class Node{
    public:
        int data;
        Node *left;
        Node *right;
        Node(int k){
            data = k;
            left = right = NULL;
        }
};
void height(Node *root){
    if(root==NULL)
        return;
    length++;
    if(length>total)
        total = length;
    height(root->left);
    height(root->right);
}
int main(){
    Node *root = new Node(3);
    root->left = new Node(4);
    root->left->left = new Node(5);
    root->right = new Node(6);
    root->right->left = new Node(7);
    height(root);
    cout<<total;
    return 0;
}
```

here length and total have been declared as global variables having values -1 and 0 respectively.
**When I run the code, the output which I am getting is the number of nodes in the tree - 1** but not the height of the tree. Please let me know my mistake here.

Comment: Please post a minimal working code so one can try.

Comment: @theWiseBro  I have included working code for the same. Please look into the issue

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you're incrementing `length` on every node.

If you're doing it recursively, it is actually very simple:

```cpp
std::size_t height(Node const *root) {
    if(!root) return 0;
    return 1 + std::max(height(root->left), height(root->right));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is more of a backtracking than a simple recursion. In this approach you should be mindful to revert back to the original state at each step. Here `length` is always being incremented. You should revert it back.

```
void height(Node *root){
    if(root==NULL)
        return;
    length++;
    total = std::max(total,length+1); // Either this or initialize length as 0
    height(root->left);
    height(root->right);
    length--; // <--- Add this line
}
```